# How to prevent JQuery from executing after hitting Cancel on popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, alert

I have a form that needs to get submitted.  After clicking on submit I have a javascript alert/confirm that asks: Are you sure you want to submit the order?

If the user clicks "OK", I want to execute a JQuery method.  But if they click "Cancel", I don't want to execute anything.  Is there a way to do this?
Here's the JQuery I want to submit if they click "Ok":

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#saving').click(function() { 
   // do something
}); 
});
</script>
```

my button:
    Save

The javascript popup:

```
function askUserIfTheyAreSure() {
var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the order?");
if(check == true) { 
  document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
}
```

Comment: Why is it important to create a "jQuery method", whatever you mean by that? Just create a simple function and call it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this way:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#saving').click(function() { 

    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the order?")){
        document.forms["myform"].submit();

    }else{
      return false;
   }

}); 


});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, like this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function askUserIfTheyAreSure(){
    var check = confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the order?');
    if(check == 1) { 
      // run you jQuery Function Here
    }
    else{
      // do something else
      return false;
    }
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#saving').click(askUserIfTheyAreSure); 
</script>
```

Really, I would use external JavaScript, so it's cached.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy whatever you have inside "click" code into the "check==true" block.
It won't be executed if user clicks cancel.

```
function askUserIfTheyAreSure() {
    var check = confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the order?");
    if(check == true) { 
        // do something begin

        // do something end
        document.forms["myform"].submit();
    }
}
```